# Select results if the newest date is older than 30 days

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table with 2 fields: `id_type` and `created_at`

There are several rows with the same `id_type` and different timestamps. Eg:

```
3   -   2015-06-10 12:01:20
1   -   2015-03-21 04:14:10
1   -   2015-03-17 04:14:10
0   -   2015-05-06 21:43:00
3   -   2015-05-13 19:34:32
3   -   2015-07-18 03:47:55
```

I need to select `id_type` if the newest corresponding `created_at` is older than 30 days (Or in other words, any id_type that was last recorded more than 30 days ago)

Expected result:

```
1
0
```

I've tried:

```
SELECT id_type FROM table WHERE MAX(created_at) < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 day)
```

Which has given me the error:

```
invalid use of group function
```

How should I build it properly?

Comment: checkout mysql function `timestampdiff` or `datediff`

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
SELECT id_type FROM table_b WHERE created_at IN (Select MAX(created_at) from table_b where created_at < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 day));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this :

```
select id_type from `table` where `created_at` >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH)
```